# android timertask in specific date/time

Tags: android, datetime, timertask

Hm, I try to make a question in different way :)

I wrote code for activate notification in specific date/time (Date class) as local (local variable). When I activate notification I crate a new notification with new date/time.

Code:

```
private void createNotification(final String contentTitle, final String contentText,
        final String tickerText) {

    calculateVakat();
    setFirstMillis(getNextVakat());

    createStatusBarNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);

    Notification note = new Notification(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, tickerText, System.currentTimeMillis());

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, VaktijaActivity.class), 0);

    note.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText, intent);

    note.vibrate = new long[] {500L, 200L, 200L, 500L};
    note.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    note.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note);
}

private void createStatusBarNotification(final String contentTitle,
        final String contentText, final String tickerText) {

    Date date = new Date(getFirstMillis());
    Log.i("date", date.toString());
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createNotification(contentTitle, contentText, tickerText);
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(timerTask, date);
}
```

In this case notification is active every time when I install application from my PC (eclipe), but if I start application from mobile, 'next' notification will not be active. Maybe my application is not service, but I do not want service, I want application with timertask in background.

If I must make service, how can I do that?

BR, Kolesar

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what you mean.

the alarm atm will trigger atm you are making the alarm because

```
Notification note = new Notification(
        android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on, tickerText,
        System.currentTimeMillis());
```

you wan' the user to input a time that you then convert to milliseconds and then you say like current time - user time

and then you wan't the alarm to start en activity when it triggers ??

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);

shut be working

im not sure if you need this line off code

```
notificationManager.notify(NOTIF_ID, note);
```

as fare as i remember it trigger the alarm

Comment: if you like making 2 difrent alarm just change the request code 

   PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

i just made a random rumber for the request code every time i run it